# How to create an Sql Server Reporting Service in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have Visual Studio 2013 and Sql Server 2012 installed but i don't know how to create Sql Server Reporting Service in Visual Studio.I have searched on google and have read that Visual Studio Business Intelligence required for this...
Please help me that where is the Business Intelligence option in Visual Studio that i have installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install **Microsoft Visual Studio Tools for Applications 2013** before you will see the Reporting Services template.

You can download it for free from the Microsoft site here

http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=44213

Once this is installed, select **File, New, Project**, and you will see a new template folder called **Business Intelligence**. Expand this folder and select the **Reporting Services** option.